# Disable "Location Accuracy" message when using iBeacon

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-location, ibeacon

I have an app that uses iBeacon. I plan to provide all of the feedback about the state of Location Services and Bluetooth to the user within the app.

The problem is: When I disable Bluetooth while the app is running. An alert view comes up titled "Location Accuracy" saying "Turning on Bluetooth will improve location accuracy." This degrades from the user experience that I am trying to set up. I want to guide users into turning on Bluetooth using custom UI.

I would like to disable this alert. Is that possible?

[image: The alert view in question]

Comment: In our app we want show this alert. How we can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. iBeacon based on Bluetooth so it just not work without turning it On.

Upd. but of course you can check that bluetooth disabled with `CBCentralManager` and inform user in other way before using iBeacon code

Comment: I understand that Bluetooth is required to use iBeacon. I am not trying to use iBeacon without Bluetooth. I am trying to disable the "Location Accuracy" alert so I can handle getting the user to enable Bluetooth in a custom way.

Comment: Oh, sorry, in this case, I think, you can use `state` property of `CBCentralManager` before

Comment: Can you clarify? Are you saying to modify property(readonly) CBCentralManagerState state

Comment: not modify, just check, and if not inform user in other way

Comment: I see what you are saying. I have already set this up to respond to the CBCentralManagerState changes. The problem is, I still see this alert view and it is interfering with my UX.